# Make checkbox in listview invisible based on item value

Tags: asp.net

Please help. I am trying to make the rejectcheckbox become invisible based on the CaseStatus item. If CaseStaus = "success" then rejectcheckbox's visible = true. If CaseStatus = "reject" then rejectcheckbox's visible = false.

```
 <ItemTemplate>
               <tr 
                                style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="emailaddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("emailaddress") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CaseNumberLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CaseNumber") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="FileUploadToRepositoryTimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FileUploadToRepositoryTime") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CaseTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CaseTitle") %>' />
                    </td>
                   <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CaseTypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CaseType") %>' />
                    </td>
                     <td>
                           <asp:HyperLink ID="FileNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FileName") %>'  target ="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/FileArchives/FileUploadArchive/" + Eval("FileName")%>' Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Eval("FileName").ToString()) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                        
                    </td>
                     <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px">
                        <asp:Label ID="CaseStatusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CaseStatus") %>' Font-Bold="True" style='<%# GetUserStatusStyle() %>'/>
                    </td>
                        <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="SessionLinkButton" runat="server" Text='Update'  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SessionId") %>'   />
                        <%--<asp:Label ID="SessionIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SessionId") %>' />--%>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                          <asp:CheckBox ID="rejectCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("reject") %>' OnCheckedChanged="updateRejectStatus_CheckedChanged" Enabled="True" AutoPostBack="True"/>
                    <%--    <asp:CheckBox ID="rejectCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("reject") %>' Enabled="True" AutoPostBack="False" />--%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the on-item data bound event.

So, say I have this markup:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:Label ID="First" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Last" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Hotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="City" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
                <td align="center">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" class="table table-hover">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                    <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                    <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                    <th runat="server">City</th>
                    <th runat="server">Select</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Code to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        ListView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        ListView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Now, lets say for city = "Banff", we want to hide the check box.

So, in data bound event, we could use this:

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.GetType = GetType(ListViewDataItem) Then

        Dim txtCity As Label = e.Item.FindControl("City")
        Dim ckbox As CheckBox = e.Item.FindControl("CheckBox1")

        If txtCity.Text = "Banff" Then
            ckbox.Visible = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

So, now we see this:

[image]

so, as a general rule to change color, hide controls etc?

Use the ItemDataBound event.